# How to enable the new search tabs feature on Chrome Linux?

Tags: chrome

Chrome recently added a new feature by which you can search open tabs.

It's there by default on my Mac but not on my Linux Chrome.

Does anyone know if this feature can be enabled on Linux?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Open chrome://flags/#enable-tab-search and change it from Default to Enabled
2. Relaunch the browser